# Is it possible to program iphone to alter wireless router settings?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, network-programming, wireless, router

I want to use my iphone to set alter my wireless router settings, and I don't want to go through 192.168.1.1 - is there any security restrictions or SDK limitations I should be aware of starting off?

--
t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from targeting specific devices and building an application for managing it, you should check out Unpnp (http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/hacking-with-upnp-universal-plug-and-play/) which would let you address device in a more uniform way. However what you can achieve with upnp is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that depend mostly (well, entirely) on the interface that the wireless router provides to the management of its settings?

Comment: Yeah. Some expose telnet, others only http.